# How do I vertically center text within a fixed height whether it's one line or two lines?

Tags: html, css

I have an element

```
<p><a href="">TITLE HERE</a></p>
```

I want the  to have a fixed height, say 100px and a background color of purple. I want the text within that  to be vertically aligned in the center of the background. The contents of  will change between being a single line of text and multiple lines of text.

I can do `height:100px; vertical-align: center;` but then then if it's a single line it won't align to the entire 100px. I can do `line-height: 100px; vertical-align: center` and the text will be vertically aligned but the box will be twice as tall as necessary if it is multiple lines.

I can't change the html to add an extra  or something. That would make things easier. I can only change the CSS.

Is this possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `transform` to center

```css
p {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
  <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Esse, molestiae.</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This wont work in case of multiple lines of anchor tag. All the lines will overlap to a single position, in effect only a single line will be visible at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Use `flexbox`

```css
p {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;      /*  horizontal  */
  align-items: center;          /*  vertical    */
}
```

```html
<p><a href="">TITLE HERE</a></p>
<p><a href="">TITLE<br>HERE</a></p>
```

Or `table`

```css
p {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: table;
}
p a {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;              /*  horizontal  */
  vertical-align: middle;          /*  vertical    */
}
```

```html
<p><a href="">TITLE HERE</a></p>
<p><a href="">TITLE<br>HERE</a></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option to vertical align unknown number of lines is by using `display: table;` for parent and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` for the child elements.

This is a sample implementation of your scenario.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .wrapper {
            height: 100px;
            width: 300px;
            background: purple;
            display: table;
        }
        
        .wrapper .textcontent {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        .wrapper a {
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="textcontent">
            <p><a href="">TITLE HERE</a></p>
            <p><a href="">Some Other text here</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You can find more details about this implementation [here](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/). Detailed sample of this scenario is referred [here](http://www.vanseodesign.com/blog/demo/vertical-centering/table-cell.php).

Comment: I already posted such solution 25 min. ago ... why do we need one more?

Comment: @LGSon in your case, if the anchor tag runs to multiple lines, it will align left to left one after another.

Comment: My table solution does exactly the same as yours, which were the one I meant saying _why do we need one more_ ... if you refer to my flexbox solution having left to left, it can do both, which the table version can't, hence me showing two centering options

Comment: You know, I rest my case, you obviously don't want to acknowledge I already gave such solution using `display: table`

Comment: And you also missed that the OP wrote: _I can't change the html to add an extra or something._